# instant log display on richtextbox in windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, .net-3.5, log4net

I've an application which I want to display logs (using log4net) on windows form richtextbox. I'm getting the log message from log4net but i could not be able to display it on the box while the GUI is responsive. any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run the form on one thread and the computation on another thread which will update the form object.

Comment: yes, I've tried using backgroundworker:- here is part of my code 
public void DisplayLog(string strPrint, ListBox printBox){
                if (printBox.InvokeRequired){
   PrintToBoxCallback ptbCallback = new PrintToBoxCallback(PrintToBox);
printBox.BeginInvoke(ptbCallback, strPrint, printBox);}
                else
                  printBox.Items.Add(strPrint);
           }

Comment: private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e){ DisplayLog(e.Argument.ToString(), displayListBox); } 
        public void ShowStatus(string message) {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            if (!bgWorker.IsBusy)
                bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(message); }

Comment: ohh now I know the code has not any problem, cause I can view the active threads while the whole application is running (the main thread and a worker thread) but the worker thread seems waiting until the main thread finishes it's work. In my case the Main thread does some functionality and logs messages. so i'm getting the log data that is processed by the main thread and tried to display to a listBox using the worker thread (backgroundworker). there should be someway to do this .... any clueeeeee ?

Comment: when i suspend the running main thread, the worker thread starts its job and I can print out just a line on the box. I don't know how it can keep printing regardless of the main thread status ...

Comment: Problem solved! Adding one more backgroundworker for the method that gets the Log. Which means the application works fine with three threads running separately including the main thread. Thanks.